# Interact with child of child

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, file-descriptor

I need to interact directly with the `stdin` and `stdout` of a process I spawn with the `subprocess`. I can do it with:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("/bin/bash", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
proc.stdin.write(b"whoami\n")
print(proc.stdout.readline())
```

However, as soon as the process forks, I can no longer interact with it. I have this test program:

```
// child.c
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
    execve("/bin/bash", NULL, NULL);
}
```

that I compile with:

```
gcc -o child child.c
```

and when I try the above python code with `child` instead of `/bin/bash` in the `Popen` call, I get a `broken pipe` error.
What I tried:
Since the file descriptors created by python are not inheritable by default, I tried changing that:

```
inr, inw = os.pipe()
outr, outw = os.pipe()
os.set_inheritable(inr, True)
os.set_inheritable(inw, True)
os.set_inheritable(outr, True)
os.set_inheritable(outw, True)

proc = subprocess.Popen("./child", stdin=inr, stdout=outw, stderr=outw)
proc.stdin.write(b"whoami\n")
print(proc.stdout.readline())

os.close(inr)
os.close(inw)
os.close(outr)
os.close(outw)
```

But I still get the same error. I think it should be an easy task and I am probably missing something. Any help is appreciated.
[EDIT] Before I edited my post I was using `test` instead of `child` as the name of my test `c` executable. I learned that it is indeed a program in my PATH, located at `/usr/bin/test`.
Changing the executable name to `child` successfully solved my problem. After hours of trial and errors, I knew the answer was going to be something that simple...
Thanks a lot to Barmar for pointing this out!

Comment: `test` doesn't read its standard input or write to standard output, what are you expecting the interaction to do?

Comment: Try `cat` instead of `test`, it should work.

Comment: `test` is the c executable I am mentionning. The objective is to eventually use this to interact with a process that is being hacked through a shellcode.

Comment: It's not a good idea to name your own program `test`, it conflicts with `/bin/test`, which is also a shell built-in command.

Comment: Your question is confusing. I thought you meant that you replaced `execve("/bin/bash", NULL, NULL)` with `execve("test", NULL, NULL)`. But now I think you mean that you replaced `subprocess.Popen("/bin/bash", ...)` with `subprocess.Popen("test", ...)`

Comment: I'll edit the question

Comment: Your comments solved my problem! I really needed an external point of view. If you change your answer I'll mark it as solved. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do I need to change in my answer? Are you saying that the whole problem was just the name of your program?

Comment: It actually was. So simple that I would never have thought of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `test` you're calling `/bin/test`, not your program.

Either rename your C program so it doesn't conflict with a standard command, or access it using a pathname so it doesn't search `$PATH` for it.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("./test", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```